# ruby-debug does not halt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

I had got my ruby-debug to work with ruby 1.9.3 and rails Rails 3.0.1.

But now we upgraded to Rails 3.2.1 (not sure if it has anything to do with this), and when I put a ruby-debug in my code, if it's on initialize it stops and I can do my debugging. 
But if the ruby-debug statement is where it gets called from an AJAX, it prints (rdb:1)  and some spaces but then just skips it, looks like it sees it and knows it has to stop there but it doesn't.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized someone had chagned rails server to run on apache instead of webrick and that's why it wasn't halting.
I had to run rails server webrick and it worked.